# OpenTracing with Completable Futures

Tags: java, spring, completable-future, opentracing

How can you associate a CompleatableFuture with its parent tracer span?

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 100)
fun myJob() {
  val taskOne = CompletableFuture.runAsync { runTaskOne() }
  val taskTwo = CompletableFuture.runAsync { runTaskTwo() }

  CompletableFuture.allOf(runTaskOne, runTaskTwo).join()
}
```

I get a span for the total scheduled aspect. What do I need to do inside or around

`fun runTaskOne()`

to get this to work?

Comment: I am search for the same problem here, since there is no instrument for CompletableFuture working out of box